# Как PHP прочитать excel файл на другом сервере?

Tags: php, ftp, phpexcel

Использую PHPExcel для обработки excel документов. Появилась такая задача: excel файл выкладывается на windows сервере по адресу `\\server\change\ex.xls`. Далее считываем файл и оперируем данными. PHPExel не может прочитать

```
Could not open \vrt-sql\Change\ex.xls for reading! File does not exist. (0)
```

запрос 
 `$Excel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('\\vrt-sql\Change\ex.xls');`

Как я понимаю,проблема с NFS адресом. Подскажите как мне с помощью PHP считать этот файл? Или предложите другой способ этой реализации этой задачи.
P.S CentOS 7, PHP 7.0.27

Забыл упомянуть что процесс будет автоматизированный. Предполагается 3-4 файлов в день и возможно ночью.

Comment: А скопировать файл к себе и использовать локальную копию - не подойдёт?

Comment: @Akina Забыл упомянуть что процесс будет автоматизированный. Предполагается 3-4 файлов в день и возможно ночью.

Comment: А какая разница-то? в любом случае начинаешь процесс импорта процедурой копирования во временный каталог (даже если это локальный файл, и уж тем более, если файл на другом компе, ФТП-сервере, доступен по HTTP или в какой-нить системе файлообмена или документооборота), а завершаешь удалением этой копии. Заодно получишь гарантию, что в процессе обработки никто не присоседится к файлу немытыми руками.

Comment: @Akina Согласен, только как его забрать с другого сервера? К примеру на крон повесить событие , которое будет забирать этот файл во временную папке , а потом запускаться обработка.

Comment: *как его забрать с другого сервера?* http://php.net/manual/ru/function.copy.php

Comment: не сработает, я уже пробовал.

Comment: Как в мануале
`<?php
$file = '\\server\Change\1.xls';
$newfile = 'example.xls';

if (!copy($file, $newfile)) {
    echo "не удалось скопировать $file...\n";
}
?>  `

Comment: А посмотреть код/сообщение об ошибке и понять причину, по которой "не удалось скопировать $file" не пробовал? А то счас окажется, что у учётки, от которой запущен PHP, тупо нет доступа к этому файлу.

Comment: `Array ( [type] => 2 [message] => copy(\\vrt-sql\Change\1.xls): failed to open stream: No such file or directory [file] => /home/bitrix/www/1c_import/test.php [line] => 5 `

Comment: Ну... с правами небось проблемы... другие способы получить содержимое файла поди тоже не срабатывают?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76639/discussion-between-ziber-minsk-and-akina).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решил через Samba, расшарив папку в которую будет скидываться excel документ, а потом обрабатываться PHPExcel